# Logging is not creating log file or storing any logs into it

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, spyder

I am trying to learn logging in python and was trying to run the basic program provided by the Python 2.7 Documentation. But the python logger is not even creating the file. So i created the file myself in the directory, but now the logger is not logging anything into the log file. Here is my code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='C:/Users/nippo1994/Documents/PythonScripts/checkstry.log',level=logging.debug,format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s ::%(message)s',)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

**UPDATE 1**

Code works on python 3.x.x but not in Python 2.7, Can someone guide me why this strange behavior of python?

**UPDATE 2**
It seems like its a problem in Spyder 2.7, didn't know this would make such a big difference. Attaching the link for the same https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem in Spyder. It's a problem in a package called `ipykernel`, and it was fixed in its **4.4** version

So please make sure you have version **4.4** or higher of `ipykernel` installed in your system.

Answer (score 0):

replace `level=logging.debug` with

```
level=logging.DEBUG
```

Also make sure you have required permissions for the directory/file.

Comment: tried your suggestion, still is not writing anything into the file. As far as permissions are concerned, my all other programs of creating, reading and writing to files are working fine in the same directory which i have mentioned in the above code, so i guess i have permissions for the folder too. Any specific check you might suggest?

Comment: For me it is working fine. 
Are you sure you are checking the correct file:
C:/Users/nippo1994/Documents/PythonScripts/checkstry.log

Comment: Yes, Im checking the correct file, rechecked it twice just now

Comment: Is your program just this much. Or is the code part of a larger program

Comment: This is it.. As i said, I was trying to learn so this was my first demo code which i tried to run. Code works in Python 3.x.x but not in my Machine, having python 2.7. Quite Strange.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like its a problem in Spyder 2.7, didn't know this would make such a big difference. Attaching the link for the same https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2572

Works fine if I run it through Command Prompt

Comment: It's not a problem in Spyder, it's a problem in a package called `ipykernel`. Please make sure you have version 4.4 or higher of `ipykernel` installed.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Can you add this comment of yours as the answer to this question, so I can select it as the answer. Your suggestion fixed my issue. Also made me realize how important it is to read the entire discussion :) Thanks...